# How to create a global svn hook?

Tags: svn

So under /svn/repo/hooks I have a post-commit script. Every time we start a new svn repo for another project I need to go to the server and copy the simple 
master post-commit script.

I noticed under /svn/hooks there's the standard .tpml. Are the hooks in this folder global and apply to all repos?  Or is this hooks folder for something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the tpml files are just templates to copy and modify.. What about creating a script to use in place of "svnadmin create", that would create the new repository AND copy the standard hooks? Or it could just create a symlink to them, so if you need to modify one of them, you don't have to re-copy it inside every repository.

Comment: This is one of the problems of multiple repositories - multiple things to maintain. Not a huge problem, but you do have to consider it. Are you handling backups and authentication properly as well?

Comment: JimT, backups are done as incramental dumps on post-commit.  Our repos don't change often, so that works out.  The dump is then backed up to our backup server.  Authentication is done with standard ApacheAuth

Comment: Joril, I have a script at the moment that does that, minus coping these hooks.  I was hooking for a global way to apply them.